# atombios stuck in loop for more than 5 seconds - Ubuntu installation error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, bios

I have an **HP G62 laptop**. Its graphical card is an **ATI Mobility Radeon HD 545v**. **Windows 8** is the Operating System which is running on it. I have a BIOS firmware and not a UEFI.

Yesterday, I decided to install **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS** in **dual boot mode** with **Windows 8**. Therefore, I followed this tutorial :http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/. These are the steps:

- Downloading the **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS iso**
- Making an **Ubuntu bootable USB key** with **Universal USB Installer**
- Desactivating the **fastboot mode** on Windows 8
- **Shrinking the C drive** to make some free space for Ubuntu
- Changing the BIOS configuration in order **to boot from the Ubuntu bootable USB key**

**I do not have the secureboot mode** because I have a **BIOS** and **not a UEFI**.

When I booted from the Ubuntu USB key, the installation screen appeared.

Then I clicked on the **"Install Ubuntu"** option and then the following errors started appearing:

```
[drm:atom_op_jump] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5 seconds
[drm:atom_execute_table_locked] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing E046
```

When I execute the **lspci -k** command from my Windows, my terminal shows me that:

```
internet@internet-laptop:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge 
Alternate
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge 
(int gfx)
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge
(ext gfx port 1)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge
(PCIE port 1)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge
(PCIE port 3)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:11.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 SATA
Controller [AHCI mode]
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 
Controller
Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:12.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI 
Controller
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 41)
Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
Kernel modules: i2c-piix4
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev
40)
Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 LPC host controller 
(rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:16.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB OHCI0 
Controller
Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:16.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800 USB EHCI 
Controller
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, 
Athlon64, Sempron] HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, 
Athlon64, Sempron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, 
Athlon64, Sempron] DRAM Controller
Kernel modules: amd64_edac_mod
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, 
Athlon64, Sempron] Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K10 [Opteron, 
Athlon64, Sempron] Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M880G [Mobility 
Radeon HD 4200]
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
01:05.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RS880 Audio Device [Radeon HD 
4200]
Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Manhattan 
[Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4727 (rev 01)
internet@internet:~$
```

Could you help me please ?